# Delete a category

Tags: link-category

I just recently deleted a category from my main menu and while the category itself has been removed, on my home page, the category title is still there.

It is for the web page: [*IrishFilmCritic.com*](http://IrishFilmCritic.com).

We do a lot of different reviews and while we really didn't cover music reviews a lot, we gave it a shot.

After a while, I decided we weren't going to even bother with Music Reviews but if you go to the home page and scroll down, you will see *Music Reviews* nestled in between *TV Reviews* & *Book Reviews*.

How can I delete not only successfully, but definitely the concerned to unwanted categories ?

Comment: If the category is not showing under Posts > Categories in the admin, perhaps it's not a actually a category term. Can you update your question with the code that's being used to generated the affected area of your home page?

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm pretty new to the developer side of things and still learning about code. I added the Category MUSIC REVIEWS a while back, realized we weren't utilizing it so I deleted it but on the home page, not in the Top Menu, but scrolling down the page, it is still sitting there. It is not linking to anywhere, it is just sitting there.

Comment: Maybe it's just a menu item? Without seeing code, it's really hard to help, but the next thing I'd try is checking out Appearance > Menus. Take a look at each individual menu and see if maybe the category link is actually menu item.

Comment: Hi Dave, I already did that, went in and checked and there's no MUSIC REVIEWS category in there, I deleted it, I'm just stumped as to why it is still appearing on my home page. Thanks for your suggestions Dave.

Comment: You got it! I took a look at your homepage, and I see what you mean. It looks like a widget is being used to generate that output, so take a look under Appearance > Widgets, and see if there is a widget area for the homepage used to generate the Music Reviews entry.

Comment: You're a genius Dave! It was a widget I had added long ago and completely forgot that it was still listed there. Thanks so much for your help, you've saved me a lot of time and effort trying to figure it out.   :)

Comment: Ooh, glad we got it! I've posted my comment as an answer. Would you please mark it as accepted to close this answer out of the unanswered queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your homepage, and I see what you mean. It looks like a widget is being used to generate that output, so take a look under **Appearance > Widgets**, and see if there is a widget area for the homepage used to generate the Music Reviews entry.